# How to get value from array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using MySQL PHP class to get the max id from the table.

```
$sql="SELECT MAX(id) FROM `".TABLE_CUSTOMERS."`";
$rows = $db->fetch_array($sql);
```

Now I want to use that max id as value and add 1 to it.

```
$maxid=rows[0];
$newid=maxid+1;
```

Above code don't work.

if I do print_r on $maxid I get that:

```
( [MAX(id)] => 5 )
```

Before that MySQL PHP Class I used to do this like that:

```
$MaxID = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(face_id) FROM `".$DBprefix."faces`");
$MaxID = mysql_fetch_array($MaxID, MYSQL_BOTH);
$MaxID = $MaxID[0];
$newid=$MaxID+1;
```

And that worked without problem

Here is fetch_array function:

```
public function fetch_array($sql){
 $query_id = $this->query($sql);
 $out = array();

 while ($row = $this->fetch($query_id)){
  $out[] = $row;
 }

 $this->free_result($query_id);
 return $out;
}
```

Comment: `$maxid=$rows[0]['MAX(id)']` is what you want.

Comment: Do not set the id of the next record yourself, but instead use an auto-increment column in the database. That is the _only_ way to make sure that ids remain unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using an alias to define the max value;

```
$sql="SELECT MAX(id) as `max` FROM `".TABLE_CUSTOMERS."`";
```

and you should be able to retrieve the max value in:

```
$rows[0]['max'];
```

So adding 1:

```
$newId = $rows[0]['max']+1;
```

Comment: `print_r ($rows['max']);` doesn't print anything so $newId = 1

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
$maxid=$rows['MAX(id)'];
$newid=$maxid+1;
```

I hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$sql="SELECT (MAX(id) + 1) AS max FROM `".TABLE_CUSTOMERS."`";
```